# Setting up Virtual Host on port 4433

Tags: wordpress, apache, virtualhost

I am using xampp to setup some WordPress sites using port 4433 and I need to setup a virtual host.

Virtual Host configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:4433

<VirtualHost *:4433>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:4433>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\cig-git"
    ServerName cig.com
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\cig-git">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 cig.com
```

I used these sites as a reference: https://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/wordpress-tips-webmasters/multiple-websites-xampp/ and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

I have restarted the xampp Apache server, restarted Chrome, but the site is not coming up. When I load up cig.com the site using the domain (not mine) loads. I don't have any idea what the problem could be.

Comment: Is your server server listening to port 4433? Check if you have a file ports.conf and edit it.

Comment: I could not find a 'ports.conf' file, however there is a file called 'httpd.conf' which has a line; `Listen 4433`